# How can I say "Some users want it" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

My first idea is "有些用户想要它" but it is probably wrong.

Comment: Drop the "it" in translation, as it must already be implied by context to make sense. 说来名声，有的用户都要, or without topic-comment or reference, 有的用户都要名声.

Comment: Hi, it was really helpful. What is the meaning of "说来名声"?

Comment: @Valamor "说来" or "说到" is an oral expression that means "As for..."

Comment: @倪阔乐 "有的...都..." doesn't seem to be very correct... Where are you from?

Comment: It would be better if you give some context, e.g. if it is in writing or speaking, what is "it", etc. "有些用户想要它" sounds fine.

Comment: @bfrguci Excuse you? It is entirely correct.

Comment: @倪阔乐 That's why I ask you where you are from. I've never heard of it. To me, "都要" means "all... want", which contradicts with "有的".

Comment: Actually I agree with your first idea "有些用户想要它", which sounds free-style but it said out what it should said.

Comment: BTW, "有些" sounds better than "有的". I can't tell why but it sounds more comfortable for me (: I am native speaker ---;)

Comment: What is the context of this?  If it's in a conversation, not in a guide or manual, I would say `"有人想要[它][啊]"`, `它` and/or `啊` can be omitted.

Comment: 一些用户想要 is wrong? I wish someone chimes in and throws an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Might a nominalisation as 有的用戶要的 work in your context?  It would translate to "It is something that some users want", for example as an answer to a question.  The pronoun 它 for innate objects is seldom used in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

If we shouldn't consider the context, I think 
“有些用户需要它。”
may be okay.
In fact, yours is probably right but, we seldom say like this in Chinese.